# Tuple index out of range,

Tags: python

Please help me run the code. This doesn't work. I have been trying hard to solve this for days. The history=model_final.fit() also doesn't work. Why is this showing the same error for the method.

```
history = model.fit(
            train_dir,
            steps_per_epoch = 100,
            epochs = 10,
            validation_data = test_dir,
            validation_steps = 100,
            verbose = 1,
            callbacks = [callbacks]
            )
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-bbb0a6f8a6e5> in <module>
----> 1 history = model.fit()
      2 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    983   if not adapter_cls:
    984     # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.
--> 985     raise ValueError(
    986         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
    987         "input: {}, {}".format(

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'NoneType'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: You need to provide more info, there's no way to know what are you talking about. But in any case the error is clear, you have empty values ({}, {}) at some point in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like keras can't find data adapters for NoneType objects. I may assume this situations is happened if `input features` and `target lables` are not given. Please make sure you are initializied your model properly.